# How to use FOREACH to query multiple times using the values in an aray

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to run a query and get the rows by iterating over an array using FOREACH loop in postgresql.

I have tried using the FOREACH loop as explained in the docs but it returns an error "cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function"

```
 DO
  $do$
  DECLARE
  a integer[] := array[1,2,3];
  i integer;   
 begin
  foreach i IN ARRAY a
 LOOP 
RETURN QUERY
select
models.sku,
(sum(models.unitretailprice) * sum(coefficients.unit_retail_price))  +
(sum(models.flag::int) *   sum(coefficients.flag::int)) +
(sum(models.mc_baseline) *    sum(coefficients.mc_baseline)) +
(sum(models.mc_day_avg) * sum(coefficients.mc_day_avg)) +
(sum(models.mc_day_normal) * sum(coefficients.mc_day_normal)) +
(sum(models.mc_week_avg) *    sum(coefficients.mc_week_avg))  +
(sum(models.mc_week_normal) * sum(coefficients.mc_week_normal)) +
(sum(models.sku_day_avg) *    sum(coefficients.sku_day_avg)) +
(sum(models.sku_month_avg) *  sum(coefficients.sku_month_avg)) +
(sum(models.sku_month_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_month_normal)) +
(sum(models.sku_moving_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_moving_avg)) +
(sum(models.sku_week_avg) *   sum(coefficients.sku_week_avg)) +
(sum(models.sku_week_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_week_normal)) as baseline,
(i *   sum(coefficients.f)) +
(5 *   sum(coefficients.p)) +
(0 *   sum(coefficients.a)) as promoIncremental,
(sum(models.basket_dollar_off) *   sum(coefficients.basket_dollar_off)) +
(sum(models.basket_per_off) *   sum(coefficients.basket_per_off)) +
(sum(models.category_dollar_off) *   sum(coefficients.category_dollar_off)) +
(sum(models.category_per_off) *   sum(coefficients.category_per_off)) +
(sum(models.disc_per) * sum(coefficients.disc_per)) as couponIncremnetal
from 
models  join coefficients
on
models.sku = coefficients.sku
and
models.si_type = coefficients.si_type
and
models.model_type = coefficients.model_type
where
coefficients.sku in ('12841276', '11873916') and coefficients.shop_descr = 'Papercrafting Technology'
group by models.sku ;
END LOOP;
```

end
$do$

Comment: The message tells you `RETURN QUERY` can only be used in functions returning sets, which an anonymous `DO` block is not. It's also unclear what you're trying to do here. You don't use `i` anywhere in the query, as far as I can see. You you just want to repeat the query three times? Maybe you want to use `UNION ALL`? You should [edit] the question and explain what you actually want to do.

Comment: @stickybit I have edited the question , hope this makes little clear, I had forgotten to place the value of i in the  query

Answer (score 0):

You can cross join a CTE with the factors to a derived table that is made of your current table.

```
WITH a (i)
AS
(
VALUES (1),
       (2),
       (3)
)
SELECT ...
       a.i * x.sum_f + 5 * x.sum_p promoincremental,
       ...
       FROM a
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT ...
                               sum(coefficients.f) sum_f,
                               sum(coefficients.p) sum_p,
                               ...
                               FROM ...) x;
```

Comment: I am not getting the output , Can you just rewrite your answer with a full query. I want the query to run multiple times and get the total results/rows based on it and the query shall run to the number of times equal to the length of the array. Basically I just want a for loop on  my query

Comment: No I won't. Your query is to long and complicated plus I don't have the schema to test it. I just illustrated the idea, you need to do the work yourself.